# Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile library structure

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

Some time ago I've created a KMM library from **IntelliJ IDEA**, using the "Mobile Application" project template. The structure was (with one root `build.gradle.kts` file):

```
libraryProject
- build.gradle.kts
- src
  - androidMain
  - commonMain
  - iosMain
```

Now, that template is missing from the list. There is just a "Library", which creates a `jvm/js/common/native` structure.

In **Android Studio**, the KMM plugin generates (for KMM library template):

```
libraryProject
- build.gradle.kts
- settings.gradle.kts
- libraryShared (this can be renamed)
  - build.gradle.kts
  - src
    - androidMain
    - commonMain
    - iosMain
```

This is just a KMM application without the actual iOS and Android platform modules.
And, it comes with two `build.gradle.kts` files (root and shared).

I'm just curious if I missed anything or do I have to configure it manually, somehow.

All IDEs and plugins are up-to-date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating new project in Android Studio, one should be able to choose between two KMM projects(KMM Plugin is required to be installed):

- KMM Library which contains only the shared module defined, and is intended to be used when one wants to add this library into existing iOS and Android apps.
- KMM Application which creates a complete project with shared multiplatforn library, iOS app with ready integration, and the Android app.

Probably, in this case these two were confused. If you had only one option in the Wizard, please let me know which IDE and Plugin versions were used.
Note: Mobile library and Mobile Application were removed from IDEA by design,please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-19232.

Comment: Yes, there are two options in Android Studio, the KMM application and the KMM library. I'm just comparing a KMM library created by the Android Studio KMM plugin and a mobile library created in IntelliJ IDEA (however, cannot see the "mobile" library in the latest release). Updated the file structure in the question. Right now, I have got two build.gradle.kts files and have to use "old" classpath plugin imports

Comment: So, the actual question is about the reason why one has to import plugins using `classpath` in projects created with the newest plugins? What exact plugins are you unable to add by the `plugins` block inside the `libraryShared/build.gradle.kts` right now?

Comment: Qs is why the KMM Library does not generate the same structure as the Mobile Library (one removed from IDEA). The classpath and two build.gradle files is not a reason, just a result.

Comment: My guess is that it was caused by the attempt to utilize the ability of KMM plugin to create modules that are multiplatform. As far as I understand, one can open their pure Android project and add a KMM module into it. So, KMM Library wizard is just creating a dummy Gradle project and add KMM module. So it seems to be a technical rather than ideological decision here.

Comment: OK. Is there any way to create a project with the old structure? Sth. other than downgrading the IDEA or manual creation :)

Comment: Probably, there is not. Is there a particular reason to have an ability to create a project with this single-buildscript structure? If you have a use-case in which that is important, maybe it is worth filing a request at kotl.in/issue.

Comment: OK. Looks like the KMM Android plugin is the way Jetbrains would like to go, for multiplatform mobile development. So I'll see https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/developing-kmm-mobile-applications-in-intellij-partially-under-windows/24160